# how to get objects from two arrays?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, core-data, enumerator

I want make some quizes about movie.

There is quiz mutable array with 10 objects.
Using core data..entity is movie.
attributes are title, actor and correctcount.

There are two textfields,

Titlefield and actorfield.

I want to make two quizes from one object

First quiz which titlefield is hidden,
Second quiz which actorfield is hidden.

and user can type the movie title or actor name.
in textfields.

And if user type correct thing, i want to +1 correct count.

What i did is..

i put the quiz mutable array into these two arrays

```
Array A (quiz 1 to 10) <<for title quiz
Array B (same as array A) <<for actor quiz
```

And Movie *quizMovie

And..
after suffle these two arrays
Set enumerators to use nextObject method.

```
NSEnumerator *enu1 = [arrayA objectEnumerator];
NSEnumerator *enu2 = [arrayB objectEnumerator];
```

Set number =1 <

And UIButton to set quiz and start the quiz

```
If( number%2==1)
quizMovie = [enu1 nextObject]
Titlefield.hidden = YES;
else
quizMovie = [enu2 nextObject]
Actorfield.hidden = YES;
```

And when user tap the done button,
     If correct, i want to +1 correctcount.

With these codes.. I can't get what i want...

Complecate..

Help me, Geniuses!!

Comment: What result are you getting from that?

Comment: If the object is from array1 i want + 10. Else i want + 1..

Comment: I suppose editing your question is in order; I don't understand what you want... there is nothing about +10 in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you incrementing `number` every time the button is pressed?

Comment: So when the button is pressed, you want to end up with exactly 1 object selected, and if it's an odd-numbered press of the button, the object should come from array A, and if it's an odd-numbered press of the button, from array B; all the while going further into the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine, then use a sorting method:

```
NSArray *combinedArray = [arrayA arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:arrayB];
NSSortDescriptor *ascInts = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:ascInts];
combinedArray = [combinedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

This is assuming the members are instances of NSNumber.

**edit**
This method selects from one array if the press is odd, a different if it's even, as I think you desire based on our conversations.

```
static int pressNumber = 0;
pressNumber++;
NSArray *sourceArray;
if(pressNumber%2) { // if it's an odd-numbered press
  sourceArray = arrayA;
} else {
  sourceArray = arrayB;
}
int indexToSelect = (int) (floor(pressNumber/2.0))+1;
if(indexToSelect >= sourceArray.count) {
  // out-of-bounds
  pressNumber = 0;
  indexToSelect = 1;
}
selecteObject = [sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexToSelect];
```

Comment: Thanks for help.. But i didn't explain my problem enough.. I'll get an object from Array1 or array2. If i get from array1, i want to add 10. Else add 1.

Comment: Oh thank you!!!!! Odd number!! Very Helpful!!!